# Refresh wms layer in Openlayers 3 after data change

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have a wms layer from geoserver and build two functions like this:

```
var wmslayer;
    var ajouterWMSlayer = function () {

       var sourceWMS=new ol.source.TileWMS(({
            url: 'localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
            params = {'LAYERS': 'poste:couche', 'TILED': false, transparent: true };
            serverType: 'geoserver'

        }));

       wmslayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: sourceWMS
        });

        map.addLayer(wmslayer);

    }

var supprimerWMSlayer = function () {
    map.removeLayer(wmslayer);    
}
```

Whene I add a new polygon from QGIS for example,to layer named "couche", I canot see the change in browser without page postback.

it is related to cache in browser or openlayers mater...
Any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The browser and OpenLayers nor GeoServer has knowledge of what's going on in your datasource. You'll have to program your application to reload the tiles after any edits.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make time parameter in wms.

Resolved. Thanks